# Microservices - What does it mean to deploy & upgrade independently?

Tags: java, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, microservices

In [this article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html), it is mentioned (emphasis mine):

> ...the microservice architectural style is an approach to developing a
>   single application as a suite of small services, each running in its
>   own process and communicating with lightweight mechanisms, often an
>   HTTP resource API. These services are built around business
>   capabilities and **independently deployable** by fully automated
>   deployment machinery.

---

My understanding is, if microservice 1 has build time dependency on microservice 2, then it is not microservice.

Considering microservice 1 & microservice 2, if the next version of microservice 2 has a new feature that is consumed by the next version of microservice 1, on specific HTTP API call, then what does microservice 1 being upgraded independently mean? Because the next version of microservice 1 has dependency (maven deploy(not build) dependency in Java) on the next version of microservice 2.

Comment: My understanding is, if microservice 1 has build time dependency(say using maven) on microservice 2, then it is not microservice.

Comment: It means that microservice 1 doesn't have any dependencies on microservice 2.  "Independent" means exactly what you would think it means here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you mean, microservice1 supposed to work irrespective of the version of microservice2 deployed? Otherwise microservice pattern is not a relevant design pattern for your requirement. Is that the understanding?

Comment: I was addressing the words "independently deployable."

Comment: `microservice1 supposed to work irrespective of the version of microservice2 deployed?` Moreover. Ms2 should not even care if Ms1 still exists.

Comment: It depends. There's no black or white answer. Can they all still exist and work without each other? If not, then you have the kind of "coupling" or dependency MS architectures strive to avoid. Anyways you are asking to the wrong audience. The coupling among services is as bad or good as the stakeholders deem it appropiate. Some times a bit of coupling is ok and affordable. Most of the time is not. It depends on the business. The goal of any architecture is to make the business strategy possible and profitable.

Comment: You have to find out whether the actual coupling among the services is counterproductive for the business or not. Simulate what happens to the whole system if the util service disapears, is stopped or unreachable. Document it and tell to the stakeholders the results. They will be in a better position to say if that's acceptable or not. Disclaimer: if the whole system stop working as a result of your test and the stakeholders answer is "meh, doesn't matter", it's likely you don't need a MS based architecure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This characteristic is opposed to a monolith and means that you don't need to deploy two services sie-by-side.

In a case of a monolith, if you want to deploy a change in one part, you have to deploy *the whole monolith*. This means that you have essentially three problems:

- Say you're ready to deploy your change, but the other team working on another part of the monolith is making a large change for one of the features, and their code cannot be deployed in its current state. Because of that, you cannot deploy your changes to production *right now*.
- Any release then requires communication between the teams. Cross-team communication is exactly what microservices try to avoid.
- The deployment of a monolith is rather complex. With higher complexity comes a higher risk of breaking something in production, which means that the team would be inclined to deploy less frequently.

In a case of independent services, you can deploy a single service right now, without communicating with other teams. They may be doing a large refactoring, or they may be deploying some changes to production themselves, or they may be on vacation for the next four weeks. You don't care about that, since your service is *independently deployable*.

Think of those services as being developed by different companies. For instance, you may use Amazon AWS. **When Amazon releases a new feature, (1) it doesn't ask you a permission to do it, and (2) it doesn't force you to release the new version of your application at the same time as it does release the new feature.** Amazon does the releases at its pace, and you do it at yours.

Note: this answer is based on *Microservices* by Eberhard Wolff. If you're interested in more details, you may be interested in reading the book.

Comment: You can deploy a single service right now... But what is the point in deploying it? When the new version of this microservice1 deployed is expecting new version of  microservice2, otherwise microservice1 will fail on specific spot request

Comment: Amazon doesn't ask me because, we are just the consumers of the features provided by AWS. It is up to the consumer to use that newly added feature, by modify the consumer

Comment: You are missing the point. A consumer would have to wait for a new feature to be released anyway, microservices included: it doesn't make sense to expect to use a feature which is not available yet. The point is not to be able to deploy microservice1 *early*, but to be able to do it *later* than microservice2. With a monolith, you can't do it early or later, but necessarily *at the same time*.

Comment: When not to use microservice pattern?

Comment: @overexchange: When you don't need it.  Martin Fowler provides a good treatment for when microservices are appropriate (and when they are not) [here](https://martinfowler.com/microservices/).

Comment: If you want microservice 1 to deploy after microservice 2, then do you also need to maintain maven build dependency. Build phase generate artifacts

Comment: “It means there is deploy dependency. Isn't it?”: yes, but this doesn't mean the service is not *independently deployable*.

Comment: “When not to use microservice pattern?”: this is a very different subject. Essentially (1) when the system is easy enough to require separation into services, or (2) when you have another type of separation, such as SOA, which fulfills your needs.

Comment: “If you want microservice 1 to deploy after microservice 2, then do you also need to maintain build dependencies.”: do you have a build dependency with Amazon S3 or Twilio? I don't think so.

Comment: My understanding is, if microservice 1 has build time dependency(say using maven) on microservice 2, then it is not microservice. Is it correct?

Comment: @overexchange you probably should not do library level dependencies between microservices as best practice would have it to standardise on a simple protocol such as the HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, ...) but if you manage a Java API properly making sure not to introduce breaking changes it could still be consider a microservice. The independently deployable thing relates to Monoliths as explained in the answer - you want your teams to be autonomous and not being afraid of breaking things.

Comment: @overexchange Can't speak to maven specifically. But, *outside of maven*, a dependency on a service is nearly-always going to be a *runtime* dependency -- not a *build*-time dependency. `service-a` should know how to talk to `service-b` and handle its outages gracefully; your build and deployment systems should **not**.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko Just because the deployment of monolith is complex for the team structuring reason(mentioned in answer - *With a monolith, you can't do it early or later, but necessarily at the same time.*), Does it make sense to change the design of application from monolith to microservice? Is the change of design always feasible?

Comment: @overexchange: in general, yes and yes. Naturally, there are cases where the monolith  is in such a bad shape, that any substantial change would require years of work.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko is there no middle design between monolith and microservice? For example, design of Jenkins is not microservice, it allows you to load plugins in runtime....

Comment: Design of Linux Kernel is not microservice. Plug-in pattern also allows you to load plugins in runtime.

Comment: @overexchange: plugins are a completely different subject, and have a very different goal, more precisely giving the ability to an untrusted third-party to extend the logic of a product in some limited way. Plugins and microservices can be used together. Your example of a kernel is irrelevant: Linux kernel doesn't have to goal to be used through REST/SOAP, and you don't want some part of your kernel to be hosted on one server, and interact with another part, hosted on another server.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko Are you saying that, Microservices are mainly used for REST/SOAP http based interactions?

Comment: @overexchange: they are.

Answer (score 5):

Truly independent deployment means you can upgrade either service in any order and stay in a working state. Obviously, having no dependencies at all is ideal, but somewhat impractical. If you have dependencies between microservices, you can still deploy them independently:

In your example, microservice 2 can be upgraded at any time, provided it maintains backward compatibility.

Microservice 1 can also be upgraded at any time, provided it checks microservice 2 for compatibility and disables its new feature or falls back appropriately if its new dependencies aren't yet available.

That second method seems a little…unnecessary. Why not just save the hassle and upgrade microservice 2 first? I'll admit that's usually what I try to do, but there are a few unforeseen benefits of upgrading microservice 1 first.

First of all, it improves your error handling and troubleshooting later on if microservice 2 happens to have problems and needs to be rolled back. Second, it's often the clients that have a better idea what that new interface should look like. I've found that doing the clients first can sometimes minimize the back and forth of getting the interface right. Third, it allows deployment on test systems with a canned or prototype microservice 2, to get early feedback before committing too many resources to developing the new feature on microservice 2.

In other words, you're putting in extra effort in order to avoid getting into a situation where you have to flip a switch and upgrade every interdependent service at the same time. Those big-bang upgrades are fraught with risk.

Comment: We have another scenario, where, multiple business app microservices rely on a single util microservice through rest API. Util microservice has json and math functionality. How to handle dependencies on deploying new versions of util microservice?

Comment: Making its interface backward compatible. Or rolling out and running different versions of the same service and migrate progressively following the strangler pattern.

Comment: For your point: "*Microservice 1 can also be upgraded at any time, provided it checks microservice 2 for compatibility and **disables its new feature or falls back** appropriately if its new dependencies aren't yet available.*" Is it possible to disable new features and fall back, if its new dependencies aren't yet available? Can you share the example code? what is the design pattern?

Answer (score 1):

To me, this is important because you can release changes in small batches and manage integration regressions much more easily.

With a monolith, you make a change to some feature area, build and deploy the entire thing and hope it goes well.  With independent services, it's much easier to roll out small chunks and make sure they continue to play well.

Let's say you have Service A which handles something, and v1 is currently in production.  All consumers use the v1 API.  You introduce some updated functionality under a v2 API.  You maintain backward compatibility on the v1 API and can 'silently' release the v2 API, and none of your consuming services need know or care.  Service A is now supporting v1 and v2 APIs, and your other consumers can then start migrating to S1.v2 calls.

With complex monoliths, this is a very difficult and dangerous process, especially when you're running multiple different applications on a shared codebase in an enterprise setting.  While microservices required considerably more discipline in many areas, it allows you to make your 'big system changes' in small pieces and without all of the external factors that make complex monolith updates a real bear.

We can somewhat liken it to refactoring code... when we refactor code, we tend to do so in small pieces at a time, check to make sure they work, then package it all up.  I tend to find a practical use of microservices is similar, but on the component level instead: we can make small updates to various components without breaking anything, and when everything is surely working well, the old APIs and their implementations can be retired.

Aside from the oft-touted advantages of requiring no outside knowledge, the service team completely owning the service, no cross-service dependencies, etc., this ability to do complex releases in small stages due to the independence is a significant practical advantage of working with microservice architectures.

Comment: But what about the challenge in design ing the complete requirement as set of microservice s? What should be the approach? Can every requirement in the world be given a microservice solution? What are the factors that decide to go for microservice approach? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46680273/3317808

Comment: So, How to answer the question, should that be a microservice? What are the reasons to not use microservice? For any given requirement

Comment: That's a very broad topic.  Microservices have a great fit in many places, but tend to work by spreading the complexity of a monolith to the service communications and configuration instead.  There's entire books written on the subject (the one by Sam Newman would be my recommendation, but I don't have the ISBN handy as I'm on holiday).  When and why to use microservices are big questions for sure.  And often times (especially with an existing monolith), a hybrid solution is the most practical choice: not "full on" services, but at least break the mono into a handful of components, etc.